# Derivative of inverse cosecant?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

I am slightly confused by this, because when I worked out the derivative of arccosec(x), my answer was $\frac{-1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, which agrees with the answers online. However this would imply that the gradient of the arccosec fubction is positive for negative values of x, however looking at sketches of arccosecx it seems to have negative gradient for both positive and negative x. Does this has something to do with taking the positive square root of x^2-1 rather than the negative root?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is almost correct, but not quite. You can think about this in two ways, depending on how you define $\operatorname{arccosec}$

Firstly, note that $\operatorname{arccosec}{x}= \arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ (this is one possible definition). Then taking the derivative gives
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{arccosec}{x} = \frac{-1}{x^2}\arcsin'{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} = -\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}, $$
and we can see that this is negative for either sign of $x$ ($|x|\geqslant1$, of course). Taking out the factor of $1/\sqrt{x^2}$ from the denominator requires choosing a sign for the square root.

On the other hand, you can do this using the inverse function rule as
$$ \operatorname{arccosec}'{x} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{cosec}'{\operatorname{arccosec}{x}}} = \frac{1}{x\cot{\operatorname{arccosec}{x}}}, $$
and again, you have $\operatorname{cosec}^2{x} = 1+\cot^2{x}$, but have to choose the sign correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was just wondering, what makes the method I used to get the derivative (considering a triangle) give the wrong answer, while equating arccosecx with arcsin(1/x) give the right answer? Surely the same problem would apply because I used the same method to find the derivative of arc sinx, although it seems to always give the correct gradient...

Comment: @21joanna12 Probably, it's that when doing geometry, you have to be quite careful with when a length is negative: it's not necessarily obvious which sign all the lengths in your diagram have as real numbers.

Comment: I suppose the problem lies in what we restrict the domain to when finding inverse functions, rather than in the mathematics itself... Thank you for your help!